# Why is "modifier lock()" needed in UniswapV2Pair smart contract?

Tags: solidity, uniswap

In UniswapV2Pair.sol(https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol), *modifier lock()* seems to be used to get lock and release lock. And it is used in almost all the external functions of UniswapV2Pair.sol.

```
    uint private unlocked = 1;
    modifier lock() {
        require(unlocked == 1, 'UniswapV2: LOCKED');
        unlocked = 0;
        _;
        unlocked = 1;
    }
```

But I don't know why lock is needed in solidity smart contract. Is it used to execute function in sequence , just like "synchronized" in java? In my understanding, in the context of Ethereum, transactions in a block are executed one by one, which means that they are executed in sequence natively. Since they are impossible to be executed in parallel, why lock is needed?

Hopefully some expert can help me understand this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the intent of the person who coded this, or going through the contract in depth, it looks like a simple re-entrancy guard in the form of a [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion).

As such, it will prevent the protected functions from re-entered in the same transaction (which would presumably be bad for these functions).

More on re-entrancy, and mitigating strategies, here -> https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/

Good answer to "What is a re-entrancy attack" here: [Reentrancy Attack in a Smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59386/reentrancy-attack-in-a-smart-contract/68024)

Answer (score 0):

It is a reentrancy attack guard. If you check the source code, this modifier is used for `mint` and `burn` where you transfer funds.

This modifier adds the require statement first

```
 require(unlocked == 1, 'UniswapV2: LOCKED');
```

then it sets `unlocked=0` and executes the function code with this `_` placeholder. At this point, if the attacker wants to re-execute the function code before the first execution is completed, `lock` modifier will run, and `require` statement will fail because we previously set `unlocked=0`.

In a reentrancy attack, after funds are withdrawn, `fallback` function gets executed and another withdraw operation is executed inside `fallback` before the balance of the contract is updated. So attacker keeps withdrawing before function is completed. With this `lock` modifier, attacker cannot withdraw again till the function is completed.